# Can a human survive without ACE2?

Tags: human-biology

I guess not, but it was discovered in 2000 so I don't know if we know enough about it. Are there people without ACE2 (angiotensin converting enzyme 2)?

It seems mice can survive, but that's not a proof on humans: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4829150/

Answer (score 1):

No obviously inactivating variants are found in this gene, which provides at least negative data (humans generally seem to have at least somewhat functional ACE2). [Exome sequencing across >200K humans has found a series of variants](https://evs.gs.washington.edu/EVS/ServletManager?variantType=snp&popID=EuropeanAmerican&popID=AfricanAmerican&SNPSummary.x=63&SNPSummary.y=7), mostly low-frequency, in the population.

Some of these variants may affect gene function, but it is not clear how, and none of them are obviously complete loss of function variants (e.g. nonsense mutations).

A more complete analysis of the data, including e.g. CNVs, might be necessary to fully address this question.